# Как в Visual Studio вставить свой графический элемент?

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

Работаю с C# в Visual Studio, сделал форму, накидал кнопок, но хочу поменять стандартные кнопки и текстбокс на свои, подскажите, как сделать.

Спасибо.

Comment: Скучные кнопки?) Извините, не удержался.

Comment: еще какие скучные!)) творчество и полет фантазии распирает,а вот с реализацией трудности))

Comment: все...дошло само...PictureBox блин))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего использовать готовые темы WPF: [WPF Themes](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/).

Comment: спасибо,не знал о такой возможности,это то,что нужно!)